# jQuery: Loop iterating through numbered selectors?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, loops, button, selector

I have a Google Map with some simple buttons added to pan to different locations.

```
<input id="loc0" type="button" value="Cape Sable (6)">
<input id="loc1" type="button" value="Florida Bay (3)">
```

Originally, I was using this code to make the buttons work:

```
var locations = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.171, -81.060),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.211, -80.650) 
];


$('#loc0').click(function(){
    map.panTo(locations[0]);
    map.setZoom(12);
});

$('#loc1').click(function(){
    map.panTo(locations[1]);
    map.setZoom(12);
});
```

This works fine, but I would love to write the click function as a loop, so I don't have to keep using redundant code. But I can't seem to figure it out.

I have tried the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    $('#loc'+i).click(function() {
        map.panTo(locations[i]);
        map.setZoom(12);
    });

}
```

But I get an error when trying to use the buttons: `panTo: latLng must be of type LatLng (122 out of range 43)`. I'm not well-versed with jQuery, so I suspect this is something simple I don't understand yet. Any hints?

Comment: i would try the exact same code you used in that "for" but changing the "i" variable to something else in case google map api use an undeclared "i" variable into the panTo method

Comment: @Lil'Monkey Tried it, but I get the error `panTo: latLng must be of type LatLng (122 out of range 43)`. Brad's code elimiates that error, but I am still having trouble getting the pans to go to the right locations, instead of just the last one listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing immediately pops out as being wrong, this looks like it should be correct.

Can you put up a JS Fiddle demonstrating the problem at all?

My first hunch would be that your code is correct but somehow you are getting invalid data in the locations array.

If that's not the case, I wonder if it's an issue with enclosure and the variables.  Something like this may help:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var location = locations[i];
    $('#loc'+i).click(function() {
        map.panTo(location);
        map.setZoom(12);
    });
}
```

I first made the declaration of the "i" variable specific to each loop, so there's no way that it can get overwritten improperly somewhere else.  I also added the additional "fail safe" of defining the "location" variable in each iteration of the loop so that you can ensure the correct variable makes it to the click function.

**EDIT**
Definitely an issue with enclosure and the variable content when accessed via click.  Something else you could try is this:

1:  Add a common class to each button, something like class="locButton"

2:  Try this:

```
$(".locButton").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var locId = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('loc',''));
        map.panTo(locations[locId]);
        map.setZoom(12);
    });
});
```

Comment: http://crocdoc.ifas.ufl.edu/projects/saveyourlogo2/map/ I tried the code you wrote up, and the pan does work, but all buttons pan to the last location, so it seems that `i` is getting evaluated during the time of the click. How might I go about making sure the correct location is panned to?

Comment: Just looked at your code, and it looks like you have the following:

var i;

//Doesn't work yet
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {...}

Try removing the "var i;" bit that you have in there before the for loop

Comment: even if he declare var i ... if it is not declared and used into the panTo method his code will generate errors, try renaming your i variable to something else like "iLoc"

Comment: I removed the extra `var i;`, no change. I also tried renaming `i` to a different variable name, but no change. I still always get the last location for any of the buttons.

Comment: petroica - just added an edit to my answer, let me know if that works

Comment: I think there's a syntax error somewhere in that code? It breaks the map and errors: `missing ; before statement
 var locId = (int) $(this).attr('id').replace('loc',''); `

Comment: Brilliant! Absolutely what I was looking to achieve. (I never thought it would be so tricky!)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because your i variable in the for loop is global. By the time the closure is executed it's value is locations.length. It's the variable that is enclosed, not it's value.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

Add a class to distinguish between the various 'types' on inputs on your page (if not too many you can skip this)

```
<input id="loc0" class="panbutton" type="button" value="Cape Sable (6)">
<input id="loc1" class="panbutton" type="button" value="Florida Bay (3)">

$('input.panbutton').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  if(id === "loc0")
     map.panTo(locations[0]);

  else if (id === "loc1")
     map.panTo(locations[1]);

  map.setZoom(12);
});
```

You may use a switch-case too if you want or a number appending logic like your loop code. You may/may not use the class and directly query like `$('input[type=button]')` if you want.

You just want to organize the code to remove redundancy but you have an if-else like logic structure to set some parts of the 'variant' code. You can then call the 'non-variant' code 'before' or 'after' the variant logic, depending on your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Downvoter: can you please tell me the reason for the downvote?

Comment: what he is trying to do is remove the redundancy in his code adding "if" condition wont help him when he get a third location he will have to add a elseif condition to his code for every new locations.

Comment: Lil'Monkey: Exactly, I would like to minimize the amount of JavaScript needed when adding new buttons.