# jQuery: Loop iterating through numbered classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, onclick

I looked at the post [jQuery: Loop iterating through numbered selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158886/jquery-loop-iterating-through-numbered-selectors) and it didn't solve my problem, and didn't look like it was truly an answer that works.

I have a list of `<h3>` tags that are titles to questions, and there are answers below in a `<p>`.  I created classes for each Q & A like so:

```
<h3 class="sec1">Question:</h3><p class="view1">Answer...</p>
<h3 class="sec2">Question:</h3><p class="view2">Answer...</p>
<h3 class="sec3">Question:</h3><p class="view3">Answer...</p>
```

I used the following jQuery loop to reduce redundacy for my 21 questions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        var link = ".sec" + i;
        var content = ".view" + i;

        $(link).click(function () {
            $(content).toggle("fast");
        });
    }
});
```

But it isn't working for all Q & A sets, only the last one. i.e.: It works for the first set if I set the max value to 2 (only looping once).   Please advise.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with @gaffleck that you should change your approach, I think it is worth while to explain how to fix the current approach.

The problem is that the click function does not get a copy of the `content` variable but instead has a reference to that same variable.  At the end of the loop, the value is `.view20`.  When any element is clicked it read that variable and gets back `.view20`.

The easiest way to solve this is to move the code into a separate function.  The `content` variable within this function is a new variable for every call of the function.

```
function doIt(i){
    var link = ".sec" + i;
    var content = ".view" + i;

    $(link).click(function () {
        alert(content);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        doIt(i);    
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TcaUg/2/

Notice in the fiddle, if you click on a question the alert has the proper number.  Optionally, you could make the function inline, though I find the separate function in most cases to be a bit cleaner.

http://jsfiddle.net/TcaUg/1/

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way to do this, would be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next("p").toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

This is also safer in that you can add/remove questions and answers in the future and you won't have to update the function.

Comment: I agree, only note I would add is that this is dependent on the structure of the html.  If an element were to be added between the `h3` and the `p` this would fail.  Also, if there are other `h3` elements on the page which should not have this functionality, that would be a problem.

Comment: yes, safer to add use generic classes to match a question and answer:$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h3.question").click(function(){
        $(this).next("p.answer").toggle("fast");
    });
});

Comment: @gaffleck Thanks. Definitely a potential solution.  But like James said, I have some areas where I'm using <span class="view#"> as well.  But this is a great option. Thanks again for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your questions in a more logical structure to create a proper scope for your questions-block:

```
<div id="questions">
  <div class="question">
    <h3 class="sec1">Question:</h3><p class="view1">Answer...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <h3 class="sec2">Question:</h3><p class="view2">Answer...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <h3 class="sec3">Question:</h3><p class="view3">Answer...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now iterate through it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#questions .question h3').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.answer').toggle('fast');
  });
});
```